# If I put square brackets directly after \item on an enumerated list, the square brackets don't show up

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=4.\arabic*]
    \item Foo
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item [0,1]
            \item (0,1)
            \item \{$\pi ,e$\}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Each item works fine except for the first one.

I can get it to work properly if I put it as:

```
\item . [0,1]
```

But that obviously isn't what I want.

How do I get past this issue?

Comment: you should enclose `[0,1]` in curly braces: `{[0,1]}`. otherwise `item` in your case consider `[...]` as its option and show instead standard number show `0,1`.

Comment: That worked. What do you mean by it considers the square brackets as its option?

Comment: `\item` has defined options to show sign before item. for example, with your code items are enumerate wit 1, 2, 3 ..., however, if you write `\begin{enumerate}  \item[a]  [0,1]    \item (0,1)   \item \{$\pi ,e$\}  \end{enumerate}` the first item in the list will have `a` on its start (please test this, that you will see, what i mean).

Comment: the braces don't have to have anything in, `\item{} [0,1]` would also work, actually I suspect the [0,1] should be in math mode and `\item $[0,1]$ ` would work as well. Square brackets in text are rather rare, which is why latex uses them for optional arguments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.